# Is it possible to withdraw an approved binary and resubmit the same binary with updated store assets?

Tags: ios, app-store

I submitted version 1.00 of my binary to Apple for review. This was approved by Apple - I then cancelled the release to put the application in a Developer Rejected state, making the app information editable in App Store Connect.

Am I able to re-submit the same approved build in App Store Connect alongside my new storefront graphical assets? Or will I need to increment my build version number and resubmit?

Comment: The build is rejected. You will need to submit a new build and resubmit for Apple review.

Comment: I just wanted to reply to this to help anyone else who finds themselves in this position. You are able to re-submit the existing **approved** code if you place it into a **Developer Rejected** state of your own accord. I managed to withdraw the approved code, add new assets, and submit with the same build. Please note, I was in an unreleased state and this may be different for applications already live on the App Store.